# Why is my ArrayList returning no elements when I try to add some inside a method?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

For some reason, when I try to add new elements to an ArrayList called "deck" using a method, it doesn't return anything. I am trying to have an entire ArrayList have what you would typically see in a standard card deck.

Code:

```java
public class PokerTHEMain {
    // Objects

    private String[] cardTypes = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"} ;
    private String[] cardValues = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"} ;
    private ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Methods

    void ResetDeck() {
        this.deck.clear() ;

        for (int cardTypesItem = 0 ; cardTypesItem < this.cardTypes.length ; cardTypesItem++) {
            for (int cardValuesItem = 0 ; cardValuesItem < this.cardValues.length ; cardValuesItem++) {
                this.deck.add(this.cardValues[cardValuesItem] + " of " + this.cardTypes[cardTypesItem]) ;
            }
        }
    }
...
```

What I use to check for values (inside of the `main` method):

```java
for (int i = 0 ; i < PokerTHEMain.deck.size() ; i++) {
            out.println(PokerTHEMain.deck.get(i)) ;
}
```

For some more information, I am using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE.

Comment: You never use your new `PokerTHEMain` instance, maybe that's the cause of your issue.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't specific about the class name; made edits.

Comment: You are also accessing the private variable `deck` within your for-loop in your main method. Either make it public or have a `getDeck()` method for your `PokerTHEMain` class.

Comment: What @TimMcYeah is saying is: you appear to have a class with a (presumably static) main method inside it. You are creating a (presumably static) instance of `PokerTHEMain` inside that class.

The problem is that when you call `ResetDeck` on your `PokerTHEMain` instance, it sets `PokerTHEMain` to a *new* `PokerTHEMain`, but the deck it is initializing is the one belonging to the previous instance.

(And you've just changed the code, so it might actually work now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you havent created a **main** method. In my example , in the main method I create a **new PokerTHEMain** Object and **Reset** the deck , then print it

```
package org.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PokerTHEMain {
// Objects

 private String[] cardTypes = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};
 private String[] cardValues = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
 private ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();

// Methods

void ResetDeck() {
    this.deck.clear();
    for (int cardTypesItem = 0; cardTypesItem < this.cardTypes.length; cardTypesItem++) {
        for (int cardValuesItem = 0; cardValuesItem < this.cardValues.length; cardValuesItem++) {
            this.deck.add(this.cardValues[cardValuesItem] + " of " + this.cardTypes[cardTypesItem]);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PokerTHEMain pokerTHEMain = new PokerTHEMain();
    pokerTHEMain.ResetDeck();
    System.out.println(pokerTHEMain.deck);
}}
```

**Console output :**
[image]

Hope you find this helpfull!!!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to use *getter* and *setter* methods. I would write a method `void setDeck()` in which you can execute the code from your current `reset` method. The deck variable should be globally defined.
In your `ArrayList<String> getDeck()` method you read the global `deck` variable and return it at the end of the method.
Also create the `deck` object in the main instance.

Answer (score 0):

As a recommendation, you should encapsulate the suits and values.

```java
enum Suit { Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds }
record Card(char value, Suit suit) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return switch (value) {
            case 'T' -> "Ten";
            case 'J' -> "Jack";
            case 'Q' -> "Queen";
            case 'K' -> "King";
            case 'A' -> "Ace";
            default -> value;
        } + " of " + suit;
    }
}
List<Card> deck
    = new ArrayList<>(
        Stream.of('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A')
              .flatMap(x -> Stream.of(Suit.values()).map(y -> new Card(x, y)))
              .toList());
```

You could even implement the *[Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html)* interface.

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(Card o) {
    return Integer.compare(numericValue(), o.numericValue());
}
        
int numericValue() {
    return switch (value) {
        case 'T' -> 10;
        case 'J' -> 11;
        case 'Q' -> 12;
        case 'K' -> 13;
        case 'A' -> 14;
        default -> Character.digit(value, 10);
    };
}
```